# Can I avoid re-installing Software in case of OS failure by having a separate "/usr" partition?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, reinstall

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have read that if my `/home` partition is separate from the `root` then in case of reinstalling Ubuntu, I still can keep my personal files. This is like having a separate drive in Windows other than `C:\` to keep my files on. In case of a re-installation, I only format the OS drive/partition.

Suppose I have a separate `/usr` partition, can I keep using the software installed in `/usr` after I reinstall Ubuntu on the root partition? This won't work in Windows, for example. The software installed in another drive won't be usable if I reinstall Windows on drive `C:\`. I am wondering if the same is true with Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu installs software in form of packages.  Code usually goes in /usr, the information about which packages and which files go elsewhere.  Your system will most likely be usable but not upgradable.  It is better to save the list of packages installed, and tell the system after being upgraded to install them again.

Comment: That is a nice idea! I am new to Linux! Is there any tutorial on how to save thee list of packages and how to tell the system what to reinstall?

Comment: For Ubuntu have a look at dpkg as root.  I’m pretty sure you can figure out the most from the manual page

Comment: Don't forget to save your configuration - see `debconf-get-selections`, and `debconf-set-selections` to restore.  And back up `/etc`.

Answer (score 1):

The /usr directory is part of the operating system and will be overwritten by an operating system reinstall.  It is strongly advised to *not* install software in /usr that is not part of the operating system.  Doing so may interfere with operating system updates, operating system functionality, or be overwritten by updates.

If you install software that is not part of the operating system, you should put it in /usr/local or /opt which can be on separate partitions and it might be possible to preserve those during a reinstall.  It is also sometimes possible to install software in your home directory, using only your account permissions (i.e., without root).

However, if the operating system you install is a different version than the one the software was installed for, the software may not function correctly and may require a reinstall anyway.

If the software you want to "avoid reinstalling" is part of the OS, you can't avoid it, but you can preserve the list and use that to prime the operating system on reinstall.  It is even possible to save the list as a config file given to the installer (such as preseed for debian based systems or kickstart for redhat based systems).   There are tools that can build this file based on your existing operating system configuration.

Comment: That is not what is being asked.

Comment: What is being asked is if /usr can be a non-os drive.  It can't.  /usr/local can.

Comment: More like a “do not need to reinstall programs” os drive.